# Jquery in header not working :(

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code in my header -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ($("#comments").hasClass("comments-list")) {
    javascript:document.getElementById('g-aside').style.width='0px';
    javascript:document.getElementById('g-aside').style.marginleft='100%';
    javascript:document.getElementById('g-aside').style.visibility='hidden';
    javascript:document.getElementById('g-main').style.width='100%';
}
</script>
```

It does not work for some reason... The following page is the one i am attempting to adjust.

http://luogocomune.net/LC/index.php/20-varie/4290-benvenuti-sul-nuovo-sito

Comment: Why are you writing `javascript:` before every statement? Also the `margin-left` property is accessible via `.style.marginLeft`, not `.style.marginleft`.

Comment: The console says “`$` isn’t defined”, which means that you didn’t include jQuery before the script where you use it. Also, if this code is in your `<head>`, then you need to [load the DOM first or move the script to the bottom](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8716680/4642212).

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful. Add a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, include the jQuery library before this script block of yours.

Then, change your script block to:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
      if ($("#comments").hasClass("comments-list")) {
        $('#g-aside').css('width','0px')
          .css('margin-left','100%')
          .css('visibility','hidden');
        $('#g-main').css('width','100%');
      }
    });

    </script>
```

Readup: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: @brigitte18 No problem. Please make sure that you understand my answer. Feel free to ask me if you have any doubts/questions.